# Celery Task State Always Pending in Django

Tags: django, celery

I'm having issues with my Celery tasks in Django. When I dispatch a task, it remains in the `PENDING` state forever, even though it seems like it's being received by the worker. I'm using Redis as the broker and `django-db` as the result backend.

Here are the relevant parts of my `settings.py`:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
```

I have defined the task in my `tasks.py`:

```
from celery import shared_task
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import subprocess
import time
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@shared_task
def run_image_processing_script():
    try:
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

        process = subprocess.Popen(
            ["python", "BLACKJACK_CARDS_COUNTING_PROJECT_2.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        ...
        (rest of the function)
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Error in run_image_processing_script: %s", e)
        raise
```

I am running the worker and it seems to be receiving the tasks:

```
celery@MrRobot ready.
Task screenshot.tasks.run_image_processing_script[120f4cd1-ee5a-4bff-a217-f59e7e074ab4] received
```

However, when I check the task state, it's always `PENDING`.

```
>>> from screenshot.tasks import run_image_processing_script
>>> result = run_image_processing_script.delay()
>>> print(result.state)
PENDING
```

I've already tried setting `CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True` in my `settings.py` and it did not help. I have also verified that there are no exceptions in the Celery worker logs, and the external script `BLACKJACK_CARDS_COUNTING_PROJECT_2.py` runs correctly on its own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try setting `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` as a debug step to make sure the task functions correctly.  You could also try doing `result.collect()` or `result.get()` to wait for the task to finish.

Comment: @chrislondon my requirement is task keeps running in the background as long as the server is alive and `BLACKJACK_CARDS_COUNTING_PROJECT_2.py` gives frequent output that I want to send it to the frontend via Django channels. but the problem is Celery waiting to finish the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery stores the task status in the backend. As you are using database, you can check in the table the task statuses. By default celery, shows `PENDING` state for any task_id, if it can retrieve it's status.

Celery is not generally used to run a task in the background for indefinite amount of time. You should consider other ways of running it. It's mostly used to offload time-taking tasks to different processes(worker) running on same/different machines. For debugging, you can run the worker in `DEBUG` mode by setting `--loglevel=DEBUG` on the CLI. If you just want to send the current status of this long running job, you are better off with manually updating the status in a database at defined points and send that information through django channels. You can use process control library like [supervisord](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor) to manage the process, if you are running things directly on the server.